# Buildfire: Android native back button not working as expected

Tags: buildfire

For my Android Buildfire app, I am using `buildfire.history` to navigate between screens within my plugin. Using the Buildfire built-in back button in the title bar works fine and correctly pops the history when pressed. However, when Android's native back button is pressed, it does not pop the history and instead seems to want to exit the plugin (which is especially a problem on the home screen as it exits the app no matter how many breadcrumbs have been pushed).

I would expect this to work the exact same as the built-in back button. Is this a bug in buildfire? I even made a super simple plugin to test the history navigation and it is an issue.

Comment: I have experienced a similar issue with my plugin.

Comment: there is currently an open issue in cordova-android: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1106

Comment: @MAS I'm not sure this is the same issue. I don't know if buildfire uses Cordova or not, but I find it hard to believe it's been an issue for a year and a half without resolution, considering how important of a feature the back button is. Also those threads mention that the back button works after the user interacts with the screen, but I do not see that in my case.

Comment: @Jeremy Buildfire use Cordova under the hood: https://buildfire.com/technical-questions

Comment: @MAS Good to know, thanks! Don't know how people have dealt with this bug for the past year and a half though, this is a big deal...

Comment: @Jeremy I agree! but in the meanwhile, Buildfire is working on a workaround.

Comment: @MAS this is already fixed but will require an app update on Google Play